# Trigger element (XAML) is not supported in a UWP project

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a Universal Windows application for Windows 10 and one of the first things I found is that the Trigger element (XAML) is not supported when styling images. Here is the code I am trying to implement:

[image]

Sorry I had to use an image here, I am getting it from my VM.

How is this type of trigger implemented now in a Universal Windows App?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you don't have `Trigger` support in UWP.

A workaround is to use `DataTriggerBehavior` with a `ChangePropertyAction` to accomplish the exact same thing.

```
  xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
  xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" 

<Button x:Name="MyButton" Width="140" Height="80" IsEnabled="False">
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Assets/xxx.jpg">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=MyButton}" Value="False">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyImage}" PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

<strike>Note that you will need to include `BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\`. You will get a warning when you add the reference but just ignore it.</strike>

**Update:**
You should be getting an updated *Behavior SDK* from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) now.

---

**Option 2**

You can always do the same thing in `VisualStateManager`. Open *Blend* and right click on your `Button` and select *Edit Template*, *Edit a Copy* and then specify the resource name you want and hit *OK*.

Then look for the *Disabled* `VisualState` and replace it with

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="RootGrid.(UIElement.Opacity)" Value="0.5" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: You're right about the lack of Triggers in UWP. I am more used to WPF and didn't realise they had done that. A bit of consistency between platforms would have been nice!

Comment: @GlenThomas totally agree. Look at the massive amount of code above compared to WPF. :)

Comment: I expect they see the VisualStateManager as a replacement

Comment: I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal app and you're telling me to reference an SDK file from v8.1. I don't think this is right. All I'm trying to do is render the opcity to 0.5 when the button is disabled. What other options do I have? Or is this the only way right now?

Comment: @Ray this is right. Even Microsoft samples are referencing this sdk... If you ever need a behavior, you need this sdk. 100% correct.

Comment: @Ray Update it with another approach.

Comment: If you're using MVVM, another option would be to simply bind the Image's opacity to a `MyButtonOpacity` property on your view model. Your view model would simply need to declare the getter for this property as `get { return IsMyButtonEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.5; }`. If you think this is a helpful direction, happy to type this up as an answer.

Comment: @devuxer, It is another solution but I guess `vsm` is the best as it enables so much more than simple property changes. What if I want to make a smooth transition from `1` to `0.5`? What if I want to also scale the content down a bit? `vsm` does everything nicely, encapsulated within a `Style`/`Template`.

Comment: Yep, that's true. If it's an animation and not just a single property change, that would be a pain to hand-implement in a view model. Still, the view model way is plenty straightforward for a lot of situations.

Comment: Upon complete investigation, I decided to go with Option 2 that Justin suggested. It worked fine and I didn't have to introduce new references.

Comment: Interestingly (with option #1), where you nest the interaction determines whether or not the code will actually work. For instance, I use this inside a `DataTemplate` and initially tried nesting it in the `DataTemplate`; this does not work. By nesting it in the affected element, it does. So I fail to understand why you need to reference the affected element using `ElementName`. Very confusing.

Comment: The interactivity nuget package seems to be dead as far as c++/winrt is concerned. Would be nice if it worked here.

Comment: @JustinXL Is this still a working solution (Particularly for UNO Platform)? I cannot make it work (various issues). I just want to make sure I am not reading a very old thread which is not working anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use the namespaces

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

with

```
<ToggleButton Content="Execute"
              IsChecked="{Binding ButtonIndicator}"
              FontSize="8">
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: How can Multi Triggers be applied?