# Is there any better way to give conditional styling in uwp?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have tried to give conditional styling using converter in style.setter as below,

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cc}}" />
    </Style>
```

and came to know that there is no support provided for using converter in UWP. So please anyone suggest me better way to provide conditional styling in UWP using converter in style.setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, we don't have `Trigger` support in UWP.

> To keep the as much as light the triggers from UWP and Windows phone 8
>   are removed by msft. We could achieve those using Interactivity core. Blend(IDE) has great support to create trigger in these technologies.

Blend allows to define a behavior for the application [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/12/10/using-a-datatriggerbehavior-to-change-an-itemtemplate-in-a-windows-store-app/).

We could define

1. `DataTrigger` Use the DataTrigger trigger to invoke an action based on the value of a data-bound property
2. `EventTrigger` Use the EventTrigger trigger to invoke an action based on an event such as a mouse click, a page loading, or another interaction.
3. `KeyTrigger`   Use the KeyTrigger trigger to invoke an action when a combination of keys is pressed on the keyboard.

*Note:- This are trigger available for windows phone,make sure UWP have this trigger in the blend SDK*

A workaround is to use `DataTriggerBehavior` with a `ChangePropertyAction` to accomplish this.

```
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" x:Class="XXX_XXXX"
```

This works for me

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid"
                   Stretch="None"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
   <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBackgroundBlue}" Value="True">
       <ec:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid}" PropertyName="Background" Value="Blue" />
     </ec:DataTrigger>
    <!--  You could add your conditions here />  -->
  </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
  </DataGrid>
```

*Pls mind this may not be correct syntax i dont have IDE now*

Similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933556/1876572

[Msdn reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/06/29/uwp-new-features-of-visual-state-manager-part-2/) of triggers using visual state manager

Comment: It is ok. But could you explain how we can apply styles based on condition using above code. i.e.,using triggers

Comment: Yeah. It would be helpful for me

Comment: I would try i dont have `UWP` in my visual studio, may have incorrect syntax

Comment: Ok no problem. Could you explain the above code you have given?

Comment: This puts the in the control itself.  Is there anyway to implement this via a style?

Comment: I think still conditional styling is not possible, pls check msft site authenticity.