# How to update all items shown by ItemsControl using a condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In a UWP Project I have a UI which has an ItemsControl bound to a set of Team objects. There is a separate GameController object that has a CurrentTeam property which changes as the Game progresses. I want to be able to have a visual cue in the ItemTemplate for the Team that is the CurrentTeam. An example would be the Current Team's name gets underlined say. The Team objects do not have a reference to the GameController.

One way is to put a flag on each Team, say IsCurrentTeam and bind to that in the ItemTemplate. I don't particularly like this approach as it means when the CurrentTeam changes I've got to loop around all the Teams except the current one, to update their flags.

In WPF I think there might have been a solution using an ObjectDataProvider as it offers the ability to bind to a method, but since I'm in UWP this option is not available.

Does anyone know of a better approach to do this?

Comment: Is the GameController available to binding anywhere in the view (i.e. outside of the ItemsControl)?

Comment: @ibebbs , yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've prepared an example that shows how this achievable. To work around limitations in UWP it uses a few techniques such as 'data context anchoring' and attached properties.

Here's my support classes, I assume they're somewhat similar to yours:

```
public class GameControllerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Team _currentTeam;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public GameControllerViewModel(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
    {
        Teams = teams;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Team CurrentTeam
    {
        get { return _currentTeam; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentTeam)
            {
                _currentTeam = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Team> Teams { get; private set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the code behind of the page:

```
public sealed partial class GamesPage : Page
{
    public GamesPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new GameControllerViewModel(
            new[]
            {
                new Team { Name = "Team A" },
                new Team { Name = "Team B" },
                new Team { Name = "Team C" },
                new Team { Name = "Team D" }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor of the page instantiates a GameControllerViewModel with four teams and sets it as the data context of the page.

The page XAML is as follows:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UniversalScratchApp.GamesPage" x:Name="View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniversalScratchApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:BoolToFontWeightConverter x:Key="BoolToFontWeightConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Current Team:" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTeam, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" local:TeamProperties.CurrentTeam="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=DataContext.CurrentTeam}" local:TeamProperties.Team="{Binding}" FontWeight="{Binding Path=(local:TeamProperties.IsCurrentTeam), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In the DataTemplate of the ItemsControl you can see that I bind to a three custom attached properties; `TeamProperties.CurrentTeam`, `TeamProperties.Team` and `TeamProperties.IsCurrentTeam`. The attached properties are defined in the following class:

```
[Bindable]
public static class TeamProperties
{
    private static void TeamPropertiesChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Team team = GetTeam(sender);
        Team currentTeam = GetCurrentTeam(sender);

        if (team != null && currentTeam != null)
        {
            SetIsCurrentTeam(sender, team.Equals(currentTeam));
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentTeamProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentTeam", typeof(Team), typeof(TeamProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null, TeamPropertiesChanged));

    public static Team GetCurrentTeam(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Team)obj.GetValue(CurrentTeamProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCurrentTeam(DependencyObject obj, Team value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CurrentTeamProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TeamProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Team", typeof(Team), typeof(TeamProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null, TeamPropertiesChanged));

    public static Team GetTeam(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Team)obj.GetValue(TeamProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTeam(DependencyObject obj, Team value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TeamProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCurrentTeamProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCurrentTeam", typeof(bool), typeof(TeamProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetIsCurrentTeam(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCurrentTeamProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsCurrentTeam(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsCurrentTeamProperty, value);
    }
}
```

To explain, the `CurrentTeam` and `Team` properties are set on the dependency object (the textblock) by the bindings. While the `Team` property can use the current datacontext, the `CurrentTeam` property must be bound to the 'outer' DataContext. It does this by specifying an `x:Name="View"` on the Page and using that to 'anchor' the datacontext so it can then be accessed by bindings using the `ElementName=View` part of the binding.

So, whenever either of these properties change, the `IsCurrentTeam` property is set on the same dependency object by the `TeamPropertiesChanged` callback. The `IsCurrentTeam` property then is bound to the FontWeight property (as it was easier than underlining) with the BoolToFontWeightConverter shown here:

```
public class BoolToFontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? FontWeights.ExtraBold : FontWeights.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now, when a team is selected in the top combobox (a proxy for whatever mechanism you use to change teams) the appropriate team in the `ItemsControl` will be displayed in bold.

Works nicely for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a detailed response. Really appreciate the effort. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF my preferred option would be a DataTrigger, setting the underline property when the DataContext `{Binding}` of an item equals the contents of `CurrentTeam` on the parent (use an elementname to refer to that).

As UWP doesn't support Trigger, you can use a `DataTriggerBehaviour` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929071/trigger-element-xaml-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-universal-app-project).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Just trying to work it into the code.

Comment: Hi, upon further inspection of the post you refer to I think I would like to avoid having to add reference to a Win 8 dll.