# Convert y / n to true / false in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I used the following code to preselect some rows in a listbox:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
       <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding f_selected, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The value of f_selected in the code can be only true or false, but on the DB the values are y/n. 
I've used a trick to convert y/n to true/false by using an object, but higher heads have asked me to work only with y/n in the objects. 
Is there any way to work with a string instead of a bool or to do the conversion in the XAML or the viewmodel?

Thanks for the help and as always sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Do you know the why of the requirement that only strings should be used. That might give away how this should be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF you could use a `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding f_selected}" Value="y">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In UWP you could accomplish the same thing using a [DataTriggerBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933556/7252182).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: mm8's answer using DataTrigger's is great if you're developing a WPF application.*

In WPF and UWP, you can create a custom implementation of the IValueConverter interface to achieve this with almost the same code. Basically, it will transform your string input to a boolean depending on the rules you define.

**WPF:**

```
public class StringToBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Equals("y");
    }

    // This is not really needed because you're using one way binding but it's here for completion
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is bool)
        {
            return value ? "y" : "n";
        }
    }
}
```

**UWP:**

The above code is exactly the same except for the last parameter in Convert and ConvertBack methods:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { }

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { }
```

The following is more or less the same for both WPF and UWP. You can use the converter in XAML to convert from string to bool:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
       <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding f_selected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToBooleanConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also, remember to introduce the converter in the beginning:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="StringToBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```