# WinUI 3, Button Style Error: The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Style'

Tags: c#, button, triggers, winui-3, appbar

I am developing a **WinUI 3 C# app** and have this XAML snippet:

```
<Style TargetType="AppBarButton" x:Key="VolumeButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="MediaPlayer.IsMuted" Value="True" SourceName="ChannelMediaPlayer">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I am trying to use this style on this button: `<AppBarButton x:Name="VolumeButton" Style="{StaticResource VolumeButtonStyle}" Icon="Volume" Label="Ένταση" Click="VolumeButton_Click"/>`.

However, I am getting this error:
`The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Style'`

Any help appreciated!

Best regards

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929071/trigger-element-xaml-is-not-supported-in-a-uwp-project

Comment: Hi! I am using WinUI 3, not UWP. Is it the same?

Comment: The XAML dialect is basically the same.